# The minimum distance from the circle $x^2+(y+6)^2=1$ to parabola $y^2=8x$?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, conic-sections

What are the coordinates of the points on the parabola $y^2=8x$ which are at the minimum distance from the circle $x^2 + (y+6)^2=1$?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint:  the point on the parabola that is closest to the circle is also the point at which the normal line to the parabola passes through the center of the circle.  But since you did not show any of your own effort to answer your question, and only asked the question with the expectation of someone else giving you a complete answer, I will not elaborate further.

Comment: thanks :) but the solution to the question begins with an assumption of a point P((2T^2),4t) could you tell me how they zerod in on these two points?